HTML/CSS Enforcing Maximum Width Of Single Text Line
I am building a web application with a title which may be any length. The title ends with a pencil span which can be used to edit it to a new title.
If the title is less than the available width, everything is fine. The title appears on one line and the pencil icon is immediately following it, so it can be edited.
However, if the title exceeds the available width, I am stuck with various undesirable possibilities:

The default behaviour appears to be that the title occupies multiple lines and the element expands it's height.
If I limit the height to 1.3rem only, the title continues to push other elements aside and visibly overflows on multiple lines over other elements.
If I limit the height to 1.3rem and then add an overflow:hidden attribute, then the title occupies a single line but it cuts off abruptly and the pencil icon is hidden as well, so it can't be edited.
If I limit the height to 1.3rem and then add an overflow:hidden attribute, and move the pencil icon into a separate element outside of the title, I still have an abrupt end, and the pencil icon isn't near the end of the title, but over on the right, potentially quite far away for a shorter title.
If I limit the character length of the displayed title using JavaScript or server-side, then I end up with inconsistent behaviour depending on the text and the length specified. For example, a title of iiiiiiiiiiiiii... would be very narrow and not fill up the width, while a title of wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww... would be very wide and potentially overflow the available space.
I can use text-overflow:ellipsis to get an ellipsis at the end of the title, and if I combine that with white-space:nowrap, a width, and overflow:hidden, then this displays a proper ellipsis, but on the longer titles, the pencil icon completely disappears and is hidden, and thus the title can't be edited.
If I do the above with text-overflow:ellipsis to get an ellipsis at the end of the title, and extract the pencil icon to it's own element, then I get the ellipsis and the title can still be edited, but shorter titles don't have the pencil icon immediately following the end of the title.

What I would like to have is a title that takes up as much available width as possible, ellipsis if cut short, followed by the pencil icon for editing the title.
<h2 class="link-title"><a href="#">Testing Title 2</a> <span class="edit" onclick="startEditLink(5)">✎</span></h2>

.link-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #333;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 1.3rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

I prepared a jsfiddle with the relevant code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) if anyone wants to play around with it:
https://jsfiddle.net/6f9sbz5u/

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

Using the code given in the question rather than the more complex fiddle, a simple method would be to give the a element a maximum width which leaves enough space for the pencil icon.
This snippet just takes a couple of em off its width.


<h2 class="link-title"><a href="#">Testing Title 2Testing Title 2Testing Title 2Testing Title 2</a> <span class="edit" onclick="startEditLink(5)">✎</span></h2>
<style>
  .link-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 1.3rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .link-title a {
    max-width: calc(100% - 2em);
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>




Thanks. I managed to get it working with width: calc(100% - 4em); for the .link-title. I appreciate your help.
